# JavaScript: invocation as a function/method

Tags: javascript, invocation

I am trying to sharpen my JavaScript skills and I am aware that there are four basic ways to invoke a function - which alter the way `this` is defined. The two I am interested in are the basic two:

- Invocation as a **function**
- Invocation as a **method**

Which is fine. The first, `this` will refer to the `window` object:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log(this);
}

doSomething(); // window is logged
```

And the second `this` will refer to the object it is being executed from within:

```
var t = {
    doSomething: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

t.doSomething(); // t is logged
```

Which is all fine. However, is it correct to say, that in these two invoking methods, `this` is always going to return the object the method is contained within (if that makes sense)?

In the first example, `doSomething()` is, in reality, defined within the `window` object - so is a property of the `window` object, even if we do not define it (or reference it).

Therefore, can it not be said that, in reality, invocation as a function is invocation as a method? Or not?

Comment: reference: with [`'use strict';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) the first example will log [`undefined`](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq3nN/).

Comment: Its just about `this` pointer. If you are declaring a function in `object` then we can say that its a method invocation, because function is now a part of object, which is defined as method. Also,`this` points to object in this case.          
If you are declaring a function in window(or not inside an object), then its function invocation, because now `this` points to window.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine defining your function, not in the scope of the global object like you did, but in the scope of another function:

```
function outer() {
    var inner = function(){console.log(this)};
    inner();
};
outer();
```

What do you think the *this* will be bound to ? What will be printed ?

You might believe it will be the *outer* function object but its turns out that it will always be the global object.

It is just as if you had written:

```
function outer() {
    var inner = function(){console.log(this)};
    inner.call(window);
};
outer();
```

This is a quite hazardous and far from intuitive JS "feature".

So, to get back to your first example, what you are doing is basically this:

```
doSomething = function () {
    console.log(this);
}
doSomething().call(window);
```

And, like Yoshi pointed out, if you were using the ES5's strict mode, you would end up doing something like that instead, which is, in my opinion, far less dangerous:

> doSomething().call(undefined);

It also gives you a strong hint about the fact that you should never use *this* in a function ;)